# Sending raw data with Axios

Tags: node.js, json, testing, axios

I am testing a server implementation and need to send invalid data to the server.
When using axios post with Content-Type `application/json` the data gets automatically parsed as JSON.
If the data axios receives is invalid JSON it will automatically turn this into valid JSON by quoting the data as a string.

```js
axios.post('api/paths/invalid.json', '{"invalid: ()',
  { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
```

The above will actually send `"{\"invalid: ()"` to the server, which will parse as valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the default request transformation to be able to send any raw unmodified data to the server with `data => data` (AKA the id-function).

```js
axios.post('api/paths/invalid.json', '{"invalid: ()',
  { 
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    transformRequest: [data => data]
  }
)
```